# Wordpress Database Memory Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm running a large Wordpress multisite install that, for each site, runs a number of database queries to display information in the respective blog. The data queries aren't too heavy however I often see this in my error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1572864000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 97 bytes) in /home/********/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1775
```

When this occurs I believe the page being called (that causes the error) stops loading and the user has to reload to access the information. I've been through every page being called an all load on their own without any issue.

Looking at the relevant line in the wp-db.php file this is the line that causes the error:

```
preg_match( '/^\s*(create|alter|truncate|drop)\s/i', $query ) ) {
            $return_val = $this->result;
```

i.e. when a database query is being executed. Something is obviously going quite wrong here as I've tried upping my memory limit for php resources. Does anyone know how I would go about identifying what is causing this error so I can fix it?

Comment: Do you know what `page/url` that makes the error?. I suggest to do caching on your `wordpress`, to reduce database call. `WP Total Cache` plugin quite good. I always use it for my wordpress project.

Answer (score 0):

Put following line of code in your wp-config.php file.

```
define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘2000M’ ); // Value must be greater than current value
```

Please let me know if you need further help.

Thanks!

Comment: Every time i allocate more memory via define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ); this new memory limit is just eaten up and the error continues, it seems there is no ceiling to the memory being used. Should i be allocating memory to each task and then clearing it somehow?

Comment: In this case, it may possible that your server has not enough memory_limit value. This line will allocate memory if your server is capable.
Please check your server settings and if its lower there, please update it there.